# Text extracted by PDFBox does not contain international (non-English) characters

Tags: java, internationalization, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox to extract text from several PDF files. The files are in Polish language and they contain Polish characters. Unfortunately, when I print the extracted text, I keep getting ? (question marks) instead of those characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your extracted text is stored in String s, I am assuming that you are currently using this to print -

```
System.out.println(s);
```

I suggest you use this snippet for printing out the polish characters properly-

```
java.io.PrintStream p = new java.io.PrintStream(System.out,false,"UTF-8");
p.println(s);
```

This should work and ? will not appear in the printed text.

Comment: Actually, I was using System.out and log4j. However, your answer solves my problem! Thanks!