# Unable to print Non English (Latvian) Characters from pdf file correctly in Java using PDFBox?

Tags: java, encoding, pdfbox, println, printstream

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.InvalidPasswordException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
public class sample {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\sample.pdf");
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text = stripper.getText(document);
    //java.io.PrintStream p = new java.io.PrintStream(System.out,false,"Cp921");
    //p.println(text.toString());
    System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

The text is read from the pdf but while displaying using `System.out.println` it shows a different output. 
Then I read different posts online and found that it had something to do with encoding and I found a solution at this question: [Text extracted by PDFBox does not contain international (non-English) characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496395/text-extracted-by-pdfbox-does-not-contain-international-non-english-characters) but I had to use encoding of Cp921 for Latvian characters but still I have the problem not solved and the output is given in this image

Then I went through the process of debugging and found that the text read from PDF is stored in exact encoding without any changes so I don't know how to display the text with correct encoding. Any help would be great thanks in advance.

Sample PDF content: [Maksātājs, Informācija, Vārdu krājums, Ēģipte, Plašs, Vājš, Brieži, Pērtiķi, Grāmatiņa, šķīvis]

Console output in Eclipse using `System.out.println`:

[image: Console output in Eclipse using System.out.println]

Console output in eclipse using `PrintStream`:

[image: Console output in eclipse using PrintStream]

P.S. I am beginner programmer and I have not much experience in coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the system out either by modifying the system property `file.encoding` or by setting the `out`. Any of the following should work:

1. `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` (or whatever you need) as a jvm argument
2. `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "utf-8")` -- same as (1) but at runtime
3. `System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "utf-8"))` -- set System.out to whatever print stream you need.

EDIT

Your comment mentions you're writing to a file. To write to a file and specify the encoding, consider something like

```
try (OutputStreamWriter writer =
         new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("path/to/file")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    writer.write(text, 0, text.length());
}
```

See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html).

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you feel it was adequate, please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: I was trying to write the output to a file and it works when I run the program from eclipse but when I export it to Runnable jar it writes to file like in Image 1. Can anyone help me with writing this output to a file and export it to jar

Comment: What have you tried? How are you writing to the file? You need to use a writer configured for utf-8. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001540/how-to-write-a-utf-8-file-with-java